# MongoDB: Remove n-th element in a nested array

Tags: mongodb

I need to remove the n-th object of a nested array in a mongoDB document. In this example I want to remove the third element of `data` in the second `group` element:

```
{
    "_id" : "wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR",
    "group" : [
        {
            "title" : "title 1",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "note" : "text"
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "title" : "title 2",
            "data" : [
                {
                    "note 1" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "note 2" : "text"
                },
                {
                    "note 3" : "text"
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

So I tried this:

```
Collection.update(
    { _id: 'wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR' }, 
    { $pull: "group.1.dosis.2" }
);
```

But this doesn't work. I need a general solution to remove the n-th element of the i-th array...

Comment: `n-th element of the n-th array.` == last element?

Comment: I mean I need to select which element to be removed. A general solution. So I can remove the first element of the second group or the second element of the second group or any other element...

Comment: So you should say `i-th element of the n-th array`

Answer (score -1):

I believe it should look something like this:

```
Collection.update(
 { _id: 'wLXDvjDvbsxzfxabR' }, 
 { $pull: {"group.1.data" : { "note 3" : "text } } }
);
```

Comment: But I don't know the content. I just want to remove the n-th element.

Comment: @user3142695 you should mention that in your question. You said you wanted to remove a specific element, specifically the third element in the second array.

Comment: I guess, that was missunderstanding. Yes, I want to remove the n-th element of the n-th array. The example was the third element of the second array.